# JQuery Local Folder Browse Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, directory

i'm struggling to find a way to add a button on my JQuery page wich allows me to browse the local drive as the "`<input type='file' />`" browse, but which give me only folders by select.

I'm open to any workaround, i just want to browse folder and get resulted path in a textbox.

I'm a bit newbie in JQuery, please if you can provide a simple example too...if i'm not asking too much.

Thanks in advance

Marco

Comment: Sorry I am confused. Why dont' you use `<input type="file" />`?

Comment: You should remove the java tag if this question is not related to java, which it doesn't seem to be. Were you thinking of JavaScript perhaps?

Comment: Even if you can get a path to a folder, what are you planning on doing with it?  You are not going to be able to do much with your path from a browser.

Comment: Hi thanks for your coop first of all. The Jquery page actually has a button which calls a servlet. A parameter given to that servlet should be the "chosen" path, which will update a sql row. I've add a java tag for error, i correct to "Javascript"...

Comment: as i said anyways the input "file" let me choose just files...and not folder...